# Capture Loopback Traffic with Python

Tags: python, simulator

How to capture loop back traffic in Python, with Wireshark i am able to observe the communication as below:
[image]

I want to be the "Man In the middle" in this scenario. As i am trying to make the simulator of a Trace32 debugger in my system.

**Edit 10-Aug-2020:**

I have tried below code, and receiving error, it seems we can not reuse the same port:

> OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address
> (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
DEBUG_PORT = 20000
MASTERPORT = 53180
MESSAGE = b"TRACE32 C"

mastersock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP 
debugsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                      socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
debugsock.bind((UDP_IP, DEBUG_PORT))

while True:
    
    data, addr = debugsock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print("Listen on Debugger port: %s" % data)
    if (data):
        print ("Send back response to Master")
        mastersock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, MASTERPORT))
```

Comment: why not capture with the tcp dump command itself..?? Are you expecting a pcap file to written as the output of the capture process, or do u want to process the packets received??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran From my observation in WireShark, the tools are communicating  by UDP. I guess as Internal Loopback chance of message lost is low

Comment: @KlausD.I tried with the socket package. But when i changed the port different between the server and client, no communication is seen. https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran I want something like this: Tool Master want to read some variable in Debugger, they communicate by UDP, as simulator there is no real HW -> Error will come. When the Master send the UDP, i need to catch it and reply appropriately, message structure is known from the tool's API document.

Comment: So you want to create a client which responds to the tool master?? Is that your requirement.. are you looking for any information in the request msg based on which your response msg will be crafted.. ??

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran Yes, exactly. As i have wireshark and API document of the debugger tool, the message structure is not an issue although will take some effort. The challenge lies in how to catch the UDP as my question: Master:Port53179 <-> Trace32: Port20000

Comment: Okay got it.. just one more question, what do u mean in the above comment when you say "But when i changed the port different between the server and client, no communication is seen". Can you share the program which you have tried ..

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran: In that comment, i use the example in the link but not working: In the link: Server: 127.0.0.1, Client: 127.0.0.1, same port is used;              My case: Master:127.0.0.1, Port53179, Debugger:127.0.0.1, port 20000.